# Retrieve all child elements' values (Linq Query)

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq

I'm trying to get a collection of values from an XML document:

```
<root>
  <string id = "STRING_ID">
    <control>
      <type> Label </type>
      <type> Form </type>
      <type> ... </type>
    </control>
  </string>
</root>
```

I have a checkbox control in my application. Based on which string is selected in a datagridview, I query the XDocument as follows:

```
var controls = from str in xdoc.Descendants("string")
                           where str.Attribute("id").Value == tagBox.Text
                           from cont in str.Descendants("control")
                           where cont.HasElements
                           select cont.Elements();
```

And the aim is to refresh the checkbox with the proper boxes checked to indicate what kind of control the string belongs to. Multiple values are allowed. At this point, I can only retrieve one value, even if there are several `<type>` children for any given `<control>` parent.

I know this isn't right, but I'm trying to retrieve all the `<type>` values present in any given `<string>` within its child `<control>`.

I will then use this code:

```
 foreach (var co in controls)
    controlsBox.SetItemChecked(controlsBox.Items.IndexOf(pr.), true);
```

To set the appropriate items checked.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        var controls = from str in xdoc.Elements("string")
                       where str.Attribute("id").Value == tagBox.Text
                       from cont in str.Elements("control")
                       from type in cont.Elements("type")
                       select type;
```

Or, even simpler:

```
        var controls = from str in xdoc.Elements("string")
                       where str.Attribute("id").Value == tagBox.Text
                       from type in str.Elements("control").Elements("type")
                       select type;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is the suggested query supposed to retrieve the values? I think it is, but am not sure, because when I run the program, that `foreach` up in my question is also supposed to print to the console each value inside of the `var controls` before it attempts to check any box in the checkbox control.

Comment: This query returns all the `<type>` elements (but you might want to select `type.Value` rather than just `type`)

Comment: Hmm, still have issues it seems. It looks like `controls` comes back empty.

Comment: Got it working. The key was that I had to change `xdoc.Elements("string")` to `xdoc.Descendants("string")`. Thanks again Thomas!

Comment: @Sean, actually you should do `xdoc.Root.Elements("string")`. `Elements` is faster than `Descendants`, because it doesn't search recursively. It's better to use `Elements` when you know the exact structure of the document

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion -- went ahead and implemented that.